# Linea Pro Scan barcode Issue

Tags: iphone, swift, barcode, linea-pro

In swift based application, I have to implement barcode scanning using device camera as well as using Linea Pro 5 (LP5) external barcode scanner.
In the application have to to check the iPhone connection state with Linea Pro 5 (LP5) device and if iPhone is not connected with LP5 then it must open iPhone camera otherwise it will scan using LP5. The scanning I have to do with any UIButton reside on the application screen.

My problem is that when I call connect() method the "func connectionState(state: Int32)" method call and iPhone connection state with LP5 change from Connecting to Connected then after I am able to scan using LP5 but when I perform scan another barcode the LP5 is not scanning and camera get open. Also when I scan wring barcode which is not expect then after rescan the device camera opens. It means connection state changed somehow. but each time "func connectionState(state: Int32)” not call.

Can anybody tell me how to check connection state of the LP5 device before each scan operation. Or tell me proper solution of the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Maintain a variable in the calling class, which holds the state of the linea pro device,

```
var lineaProState;
```

assign the value to this variable in, `connectionState(_ state: Int32)` method

```
lineaProState = state;
```

Then before scanning the item/barcode, check the state variable:

```
if(lineaProState==0)
                {
                    //disconnected...
                    //call the lib.conncet() method
                    lib.connect()
                }
                else if(lineaProState==1)
                {
                    //connecting...wait for connect to finish
                }
                else if(lineaProState==2)
                {
                    //connected..Proceed with scanning
                }
```

---

**Option2:** Call the `lib.connect()` method from the library every time you try to scan the new barcode? This in turn, will invoke the `connectionState(_ state: Int32)` method and you can check the device status, whether it is connected.

This will do the trick.Cheers!!!